# Populate TextBox from ComboBox

Tags: ms-access

I created a form in Microsoft Access and added a ComboBox populated from a database table.

I also have a TextBox which I want to populate from a Query when the ComboBox changes.

My query is the following:

```
SELECT C.Nome
FROM Categories AS C INNER JOIN Users AS U ON C.Code = U.CategoryCode
WHERE C.Code = @Code;
```

@Code should be the value on the ComboBox.

I keep getting a #Name? value in the ComboBox.

Does anyone knows what might be wrong?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Say your combo box was named `cbxCategoryCode` and your text box was named `txtUserNome`. You could achieve the desired effect by setting the `Control Source` of your text box to

```
=DLookUp("Nome","Users","CategoryCode=""" & [cbxCategoryCode] & """")
```

and using the following as the `[Event Procedure]` of the `After Update` event for your combo box

```vb
Private Sub cbxCategoryCode_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtUserNome.Requery
End Sub
```